# Get order ids with status = "canceled/declined"

Tags: checkout, orders, api, order-status

currently i'm getting all orders id's from some code on my success.phtml page.

What about if orders get canceled. How to i only pass information along on canceled or declined and would they still hit the success.phtml page... maybe if it was declined after the fact.... ???

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId().'&event_status=decline'
```

Obviously the code above gets the id but always (forces) to pass a declined status.

This is part of a rest api but i'm only looking to send orders that have been declined.

```
event_status='.Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 'cancelled')
```

I only want to pass the order id's that are cancelled. would the above work as the second part?

Answer (score 0):

```
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('canceled')));
```

This might be helpful. Taken from this answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524390/filter-magento-order-collection)

Also you can `->addAttributeToSelect('id')`

Answer (score 0):

> Create a block

```
<?php


namespace ....;


class test extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{


    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context  $context

     */
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }

    public function getOrderCollection(){
        $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('status','cancelled');
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

> phtml file for block or get id

```
$id = $block->getOrderCollection()->getId();
echo $id
```